# Syntax error when killing process tree through Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I am trying to kill a process tree using this shell command:

```
kill -TERM -- -3333
```

so in python I use `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.call(['kill', '-TERM', '--', '-3333'])
```

the process is terminated as expected but I get this message:

```
ERROR: garbage process ID "--".
Usage:
  kill pid ...              Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
  kill signal pid ...       Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -s signal pid ...    Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -l                   List all signal names.
  kill -L                   List all signal names in a nice table.
  kill -l signal            Convert between signal numbers and names.
```

Why do I get this message and what am I doing wrong?

I am using Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: There are (at least) two "kills".  There is (usually) `/bin/kill` and the shell builtin.  If you want the shell builtin then use `shell=True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the `kill` command an argument it doesn't recognise. You could simply drop the `--`:

```
subprocess.call(['kill', '-TERM', '-3333'])
```

You probably should be passing in the PID without a dash as well, if `--` is not supported, neither will a negative PID; at which point you'd be signalling just the single process.

Note that you are not executing this through a shell, while your shell *probably* has its own `kill` command implementation, Python instructs the OS to find the first `kill` *binary executable* on the path instead. The shell built-in may accept `--` but that's not the command you are executing here.

If you *must* use the shell built-in, then you'll have to set `shell=True` and pass in a string command line:

```
subprocess.call('kill -TERM -- -3333', shell=True)
```

This uses `/bin/sh`; you can set a different shell to run the command through with the `executable` argument:

```
subprocess.call('kill -TERM -- -3333', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Last but not least, you may not need the `kill` command *at all*. Python can send signals directly with the [`os.kill()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill):

```
import os, signal

os.kill(3333, signal.SIGTERM)
```

and the [`os.killpg()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.killpg) can send a signal to a process group:

```
import os, signal

os.killpg(3333, signal.SIGTERM)
```